# Is there a good way to determine device width in code?

Tags: angular

I would like to find out`device width` to make changes to my components accordingly. I have a solution in mind using the `@HostListener` on `window:resize`, but will it have any performance issues? Or is there another way to find out the`device width` in code?

Comment: `window.outerWidth`

Comment: I need to watch for changes. The behavior that HostListener provides

Comment: When using angular material/cdk you could checkout [this](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the Breakpoint Observer by @angular/cdk.

It is a quite simple API: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

U can easily subscribe to it and observe screen size changes by default or custom breakpoints, which is in turn a lot cheaper if u only need certain screen widths.

Kind regards

Comment: That's what i was looking for. I'm already using breakpoints in my stylesheets, but i did not want to add `display:none` to components on certain devices because it doesn't destroy the component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get it once:

```
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

If you wanna keep it updated on resize:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

By using `Platform` [`width()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#width) and [`height()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#height)
and using methods is preferred since the dimensions are cached values, which reduces the chance of multiple and expensive DOM reads

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

...
private width:number;
private height:number;

constructor(private platform: Platform){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.width = platform.width();
        this.height = platform.height();
    });
}
```

Comment: So there is no 'cheap' way of having a ```real-time``` value.

Comment: @BogdanB `real-time` means each second you're accessing the DOM which for sure cost, You have another option which's `Break Point` , Feel free to read about it it might help